# in MathGL how to get values an array after math operation

Tags: c, mathgl

I have a code which perfectly draws a sine wave graph

```
y = mgl_create_data_size(100,1,0);
mgl_data_modify(y,"0.4*y+0.1+sin(6*pi*x)",0);
gr = mgl_create_graph(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
mgl_plot(gr,y,". ","");
mgl_box(gr);
```

Now that the variable `y` is a MathGL data type `HMDT`
How I will get numeric values from it

I see there is function which `mgl_data_get_value(y,i,j,0);`

but it only accepts long data type and it always returns NaN

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer that, I am trying to assume `j` as incremental value.

But, base on trial and error based, when I set `j` as `0` I am getting all the `100` graph values which applied based on the `MathGL` formula `0.4*y+0.1+sin(6*pi*x)`.

So the assumption of the function `mgl_create_data_size` is
If the data is set using `100,1,0` which is `nx,ny,nz`
`nx` = `100` - Total number of X axis values
`ny` = `1` - is only one Y value for each X value
`nz` = `0` - is assumed as 0, there is no z axis
the function which can get each graph value is

```
mgl_data_get_value(y,i,0,0)
```

Example of `10` values for the same formula

```
var y1 = mgl_create_data_size(10,1,0)
mgl_data_modify(y1,"0.4*y+0.1+sin(6*pi*x)",0)
for(i in 0..10-1) {
   println(mgl_data_get_value(y1,i,0,0))
}
```

The output is

```
0.1
0.9660254037844387
-0.7660254037844384
0.09999999999999976
0.9660254037844391
-0.7660254037844387
0.09999999999999952
0.9660254037844401
-0.7660254037844377
0.09999999999999927
```

The graph in Excel for the above values is
[image]
This is very help full to use MathGL in applied mathematics in data generation as one of the light weight libraries